# ConnectionError: Failed to connect in mssql in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to connect to my database using MSSQL Server using NodeJS

but i have an error

> { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.10.17.199:undefined in 15000ms

here is the beginning of my code:

```
   var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'mat1',
        password: 'a',
        server: '10.10.17.199\\MSSQLLocalDB', 
        database: 'master' ,
        port: 1433
    };

    //\\MSSQLLocalDB

    console.log("passed 1")

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: Maybe this answer from "alan" will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185970/18392113

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error trying to connect to the server. Maybe you dont have access to the server. Also can happen is timing out to connect, if thats the case you can modify the connection timeout setting in the connection configuration.