# ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 15000ms

Tags: sql-server, node.js, electron, knex.js

I am using KnexJs attempting to connect to a local Microsoft SQL Server Express.   However, with the below configuration, I am getting an error. I've followed the typical steps, but I'm still getting the error.

What I've tried:

1. Set up a SQL Server authentication login for the database
2. Enable SQL Server authentication on the server
3. Enable TCP/IP on the server
4. Restart the Windows services
5. Restart the SQL Server through SQL Server Management Studio
6. Verify ability to log in through SQL Server Management Studio

Configuration / query code:

```
    let mssql = knex({
        client: 'mssql',
        connection: {
          host: 'localhost\\sqlexpress',
          user: 'test',
          password: 'test',
          database: 'AdventureWorks2017',
          // port:1433,
          // options: {
          //   trustedConnection: true
          // },
          useNullAsDefault: true
        }
      });

    mssql.raw('select 1 as result').then(function (result) {
      console.log('result');
      console.log(result);
      mainWindow.webContents.send('testConnectionResponse', result === 1);
      event.sender.send('testConnectionResponse', result === 1);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      mainWindow.webContents.send('query-error', err);
    }).finally(() => {
      mssql.destroy();
    });
```

Error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 15000ms

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that I also needed to enable the SQL Server Browser windows service like so:

1. Navigate to "Services"
2. Select "Properties" on "SQL Server Browser"
3. Flip "Start up type" to "Automatic"
4. Start the service

Success!

Comment: I was trying to solve this issue since last four hours, tried sample code from the npm mssql package website but not worked. Though it could connect to my azure database of cloud. But no where it was showing this could be even a bottle neck. Thnx for the solutoin.

Comment: This is crazzy... been looking at this for more than 2 hours with solutions leading to TCP/IP settings.. and nothing worked.. was almost giving up then this showed up! Thanks a load.. its worked like magic!